# how to get correct path in jsp

Tags: jsp, path, tomcat8

I want define a path inside a jsp file

```
<% String paths = "/test/abc.txt"; %>
```

but it always shown me - file cannot be found error
I'm using tomcat8 server and my index.jsp file placed in the same level of txt file, all inside test folder.

```
webapps/test/index.jsp
webapps/test/abc.txt
```

Comment: add complete exception stack trace and the code how you reading file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your path is inside the webapp context, use `application.getRealPath("/")`:

```
<% String paths = application.getRealPath("/") + "abc.txt"; %>
```

Comment: it works, thanks, do you mind to tell me if i put my stuffs inside webapp/ROOT then how?